# Building two outputs from a Xcode project

Tags: ios, swift

I have a project in `Xcode` (`swift`) and I want to build it in two ways. a build with a framework (embedded in project) and another build without that framework.
Is there any way to do this with minimum changes for each update?
I means something like `if #available` statement which determine whether a particular framework is embedded in project or not.
something like:

```
if ... {
   import framework
}
```

Comment: Builds are usually associated with a scheme. Is there a reason you can't do it that way?

Comment: @dfd I should distribute two versions of app for each update. I want to make it easier.

Comment: @dfd I don't know how can I do it. if you think it can be helpful please describe that. thanks

Comment: You could try a custom target.

Comment: @Cristik can you explain more?

Comment: You could try adding "Aggregate" target, depending on two other targets that reference the same library code, and that have the build settings differences you mentioned.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally, I found my solution.
In this case we should do four main tasks:

1. creating a scheme for separate builds
2. defining an `Active Compilation Condition`
3. excluding the frameworks we want to remove from build.
4. putting depended codes in `#if` scope.

First of all, we need to create two build configurations by duplicating and renaming `debug` and `release` build configurations (In this case, I named those as `Debug_no_charkhune` and `Release_no_charkhune`). For first step, with choosing main scheme and clicking on `duplicate scheme` in `edit scheme` page our new scheme is ready. just remember to change its name and build configurations in all tabs with new build configurations. For second step, we should go to `Build settings` tab in project setting page and set `Active Compilation Condition` values for wanted schemes. (In this case I defined `CHARKHUNE` as a condition).[image: active condition]

Now we need to exclude unwanted frameworks in new scheme. for this, we should add framework name as a string in `Excluded source file names` section in project's builds settings like image:[image: excluded files]

Now we're ready for it. we should put codes that are related to excluded framework in an if statement like this:

```
#if CHARKHUNE
    import charkhunePayment
#endif
```

At last. thanks @Cristik and @dfd for their advices.
Hope you enjoy ;)